# How to pop then immediately push xamarin pages

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

my current navigation stack has two pages. First is page A, second is Page B. When I click my button, It'll add a new page to the navigation stack, Page C.

May I ask how do I display Page C and remove Page B, or remove page B and display page C.

I've tried the following

```
await Navigation.PopAsync()
await Navigation.PushAsync(new CustomPage())
```

The issue i'm having with this is that the page pops successfully, but the new page isn't visible. I immediately see page A. May I ask how do I pop the current page and immediately show another.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Instead of popping the page and then trying to push the new page. I would push your new page then remove the previous page from the `NavigationStack`.

```
var previousPage = Navigation.NavigationStack.LastOrDefault();
await Navigation.PushAsync(new CustomPage());
Navigation.RemovePage(previousPage);
```

Comment: For me, it does remove the page, but this breaks the back navigation on Android on the destination page.

Comment: This works, thanks! Would you like to explain why pop() then push() does not work, even after we put those `await`s?

Answer (score 0):

You can also Remove every Page from the NavigationStack in the OnAppearing Method from the next Page. In this example the first Page...

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
    {
        // Remove LoginPage from NavigationStack
        if (Navigation.NavigationStack.Count > 1)
        {
            Page page = Navigation.NavigationStack.First();
            if (page != null && page != this)
            {
                Navigation.RemovePage(page);
            }
        }
        base.OnAppearing();
    }
```